# Copy 1 file to multiple folders taken from a list written in a *.txt file.(Windows cmd)

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd, copy

I have a problem copying a file named "file.png" to multiple folders taken from a list-of-folders.txt. (using Windows cmd/*.bat).

EG: 

source/file.png



destination/Folder1

destination/Folder2

destination/Folder3

destination/Folder4

destination/Folder5

etc...



Folder list where I want to copy file.png:

list-of-folders.txt:

Folder2

Folder4

Folder5


Copy source/file.png to folders from list-of-folders.txt only using cmd(*.bat).


Is it possible to do this with Windows cmd(*.bat)?


Thanks,

ukw.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the bat file to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: set src_folder=C:\Users\dell\Desktop\copy 1 file to multiple folders\source\overlay.png
set dst_folder=C:\Users\dell\Desktop\copy 1 file to multiple folders\dest
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (File-list.txt) DO (
    xcopy /S/E/U "%src_folder%" "%dst_folder%\%%i\dist"
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem:

```
@echo off
set src_folder=C:\test\source\overlay.png
set dst_folder=C:\test\dest
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (list.txt) do xcopy "%src_folder%" "%dst_folder%\%%i"
```